# How to include an external domain in Google Analytics funnel step

Tags: google-analytics

I want to include an external domain in a goal funnel step, I'm currently tracking a single domain.

The external domain is my shopping cart = mycart

```
Goal url /mydomain/payment-complete

Step1 /mydomain/something
Step2 /mydomain/something-else
Step3 /mycart/checkout
step4 /mycart/complete
```

I've had a look around the forums but a bit confused as to the correct method.

Many thanks